# I get this "Error: Font's can only have scale applied" when I try to add a location to my text (trying to do small animation

Tags: error

I am trying to add a location on one end of a grid and want to do the same on the other end so that the animation will go from one end to the other. But when I try to add a location for the text, it says "Report: Error Font's can only have scale applied: Text". Text is just the name of the text.

PS: Blender noobie here. I was watching a tutorial but they didnt have this problem and Im not sure how to fix it. I also didnt see them convert it to a mesh if that is what needs to be done.

Comment: You can animate the location of a text-object in the same way as any other geometry. What you can't do is adjust the location of its object-origin with respect to its geometry, except by using its internal alignment settings.  Unless you convert the text to a mesh?